running next-js on Nginx server gives 404 error on resources and links
Im hosting nextJs site on nginx.
this is my config :
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        root /var/www/html/;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name a.com;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

}

when i try to access my site its give me 404 error on statics :

and if i add this line the sites static loads well i cant naviage the site :
`       location /_next/static/ {
                alias /var/www/html/dist/static/;
                expires 365d;
                access_log off;
        }
`

and it gives me this error :
**_next/data returns 404 (NGINX)**

Im running my next.js with pm2 npm
changing the nginx config

Remove try_files directive, using try_files and proxy_pass together makes no sense. Using the location /_next/static/ { ... } block is a right thing, it is better to let nginx serve static files itself.

@IvanShatsky thanks that do tricks. can you post it as answer please

you can try to remove the line of
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

and by default nextjs build directory is .next/static
you can try change alias path into
location /_next/{
    alias /path/.next/;
    expires 365d;
    access_log off;
}

